# Lisp deleting data from list

Tags: list, lisp, predicate

```
'((A 0) (K 1) (E 1) (H 2) (I 2) (G 2) '3 (NIL 3) (J 3) (J 3) '4 (NIL 4) '4 (NIL 4)))
```

How do I delete `'3` and `'4` from the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Lisp

```
'3
```

is simply a shorthand for

```
(quote 3)
```

so you need to use `remove-if` passing a predicate function that will check if the element being passed is a list of two elements where the first element is the symbol `quote`.